# Asynchronous task in webforms

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, powerbi

i am facing some problems in calling authorization task using powerbi api.It throws `AggregateException` exception at `Authorize().Wait();`.I also googled it but unable to find any solution for this. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code for `Page_Load` function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        credential = new UserCredential(Username, Password);
        Authorize().Wait();
        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            EmbedToken embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(<groupId>, <reportId>, new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId:<datasetId>));
            Report report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(<groupId>,<reportId> );
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is embed token");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(embedToken);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this is embed url");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(report.EmbedUrl);


        }

}
```

In this function i am extracting embed token and embed url and print that in the output window and below is the authroization function code

```
private static Task Authorize()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        authenticationResult = null;
        tokenCredentials = null;
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/");

        authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, clientId, credential);

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please inspect the innerexception(s) of the `AggregateException` and make sure to post all the info. And why are you using `Task.Run` in this scenario? It is not needed since `AcquireTokenAsync` is already returning a `Task`. Also, you should remove the blocking calls and change the signature to protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `AggregateException` there is the exception what originally was thrown. The `AggregateException` is like a wrapper for the `Task` when 1 or more exceptions has thrown (more can be when you are chaining Tasks e.g. `ContinueWith`).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx

If you really want to have the exception that has thrown, use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Wait()`.

However, avoid using `Wait()` on a `Task` when using Webforms. The best approach on getting Webforms running async tasks in the page lifecycle hooks is by using the `PageAsyncTask` as a wrapper for your async methods and register this by using `RegisterAsyncTask(PageAsyncTask task)`. Also, make sure you have specified the Async="true" attribute on the page itself.

Wrap the Authorize method like so: `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(Authorize))`;

An full example can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Do not use `async void Page_Load` since this will lead to unexpected behavior, only in Windows Forms this will work since there is an UI thread. Please see this blog post for reference:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

The `Authorize` method can be optimized by removing the Task.Run, since you can already have an async method.

```
private static async Task Authorize()
{
    authenticationResult = null;
    tokenCredentials = null;
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/");

    authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, clientId, credential);

    if (authenticationResult != null)
    {
        tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
    }
}
```

Notice the 'async' keyword in the method and that the Task.Run is removed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now i am gettting AurgumentNullException at `var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials)` this line.

Comment: Is the `authenticationResult` empty? According to the `Authorize` method you have an if-statement wrapped on the tokenCredentials. And is the `ApiUrl` defined?

Comment: Yes `ApiUrl` is defined but  i dnt know for some reason it is not going into the `Authorize()` task as i checked it by priniting value to the output window in ` Task Authorize()` function

Comment: When using breakpoints (or printing to the output) it should run fine. I have an example here:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authorize().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static Task Authorize()
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            });
        }

Comment: i forgot to add `Async="true"` in Aspx page,that is why it is not calling asynchronous method

Comment: Ok, do you now have the Exception details and is your issue now resolved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177723/discussion-between-stephan-oomen-and-mohsin-mushtaq).